# Read this fantasy book about 25 + years ago (it was definitely written prior to 1999) and was about a moon elf named Selene

Tags: story-identification, books

I have tried searching for this book online for the past 5+ years, but keep coming up empty. I also remember a male character's name was Kael so I used Google's Bard AI last night and it actually gave me an excerpt from the book that, but then gave me the wrong book title and author!! Here's the excerpt:

> Selene ran through the woods, her bare feet silent on the soft earth. The moon was full, and its silvery light painted the forest in an ethereal glow. Selene's long, silver hair flowed behind her like a banner, and her skin glowed with the same otherworldly light as the moon.
>
> Selene was a moon elf, one of the fairest creatures in the universe. Her people lived on the moon, in cities carved out of the living rock. They were a race of artists, poets, and musicians, and they lived in harmony with nature.
>
> Selene had always been drawn to the Earth, the home of humans. She had heard stories of their passion, their creativity, their destruction. She longed to see it all for herself.
>
> As Selene ran, she thought of the stories her mother had told her about humans. They were said to be a strange and contradictory race, capable of great love and great hate. Selene was curious to see if the stories were true.
>
> Suddenly, Selene heard a sound. She froze, her heart pounding in her chest. She could hear footsteps, soft and stealthy.
>
> Selene turned and saw a young man standing in the clearing. He was tall and handsome, with dark hair and eyes. He was dressed in a simple loincloth, and he was armed with a bow and arrow.
>
> The young man stared at Selene, his eyes wide with surprise. Selene was startled too, but she quickly recovered her composure.

I have tried Googling the whole except and parts of it and tried ChatGPT, but get no hits. It's killing me lol! How I can remember the name of the character, but not the title to find it is making me crazy. Help!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm afraid that "excerpt" looks like pure AI hallucination.  Is there anything concrete you know about the story other than "moon elf selene?"

Comment: Hi DavidW! Thanks for responding. I would have thought the same, and it's possible AI messed up some of it, but that's one of the main scenes from the book I remember as it was in the opening of the book. The basis of the book was she was from the moon realm (fantasy, not sci-fi), she was expected to marry a prince from the sun realm, but they had to travel to the earth realm. She met a man there and fell in love with him. My memory is very spotty on anymore helpful details, unfortunately.

Comment: @davidW - You're not wrong. If you use Google books to search for individual passages you can see where Bard has generated this from. It's culled from a bunch of different sources; "her bare feet silent on the soft earth" is copied from a book called *Ironside: A Modern Faerie Tale*. The bit about "silver hair flowing like a banner" is copied from *Wit'ch War: The Banned and the Banished* (Book Three). The "soft and stealthy footsteps" are from *The Midnight Swan*, etc etc

Comment: @Valorum I bow down before your dedication.

Comment: @DavidW -It's possibly worth checking some of these out. Maybe OP can remember some specific passages that are from their book that we can search for...

Comment: The Moon Chronicles (2012) contains a character called Selena who's a moon elf. She lives in the land of Kraal; https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/The_Moon_Chronicles/ASdRAAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0

Comment: Is it possible that it's a D&D tie-in novel? I ask because in Forgotten Realm, there are moon elves and Greyhawk had an elf kingdom called Celene.

Comment: @Moriarty I was wondering about *Forgotten Realms* myself; there were also "sun elves"  in that setting, so it's the closest fit I've come up with so far.  And there were a *bunch* of associated novels published, even discounting all the Drizzt stuff.

Comment: You guys are amazing! I appreciate your dedication in helping me! I was 13 when I read this book, so it could be a tie-in novel. AI tying those passages together like that is wild! I do specifically remember the book opening with the girl running naked in the moonlight with flowing silver hair and a man seeing her so I know that it was accurate to some degree. Bard recommended "The Moon Riders- by Catherine Asaro" but she didn't write that book, Theresa Tomlinson did. I still went down a rabbit hole last night reading the summaries of several of each author's books but no luck.

Comment: I'll just read all of these books instead and maybe someday I'll happen across it!

Comment: Kael... As in a Kael'thas a warcraft blood elf prince?

Answer (score 5):

Could this be [*Evermeet: Island of the Elves*](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Evermeet:_Island_of_Elves) by Elaine Cunningham?

There's an incident that quite closely matches your comment description ("*I do specifically remember the book opening with the girl running naked in the moonlight with flowing silver hair and a man seeing her*") as well as repeated mention of moon elves and whatnot.

> “I thank you for your welcome, Sharlario Moonflower,” the female said
> in her low, musical voice. Before the Moon elf recovered from the
> shock of hearing himself addressed by name, the stranger shrugged back
> her cloak. Hair the color of starlight spilled over her naked black
> shoulders in gleaming waves. A silvery aura clung to her hair, a
> wondrous, magical light that could not be explained solely as
> reflected firelight.
>
> Cornaith, who had risen with his father to greet their visitor, sank
> to one knee. His face was suffused with awe, and he gazed at the ebony
> goddess—for that she certainly was—as if she was the answer to that
> question which every soul felt, but no words could frame.
>
> [image]

The blurb starts with the word "Serene" which could possibly have been mistaken for a name.

> **Serene, beautiful, inviolate.**
> Rich in magic and treasure, to those who hear of its legends it is the ultimate paradise. To the beleaguered elves of Toril it is the ultimate refuge. But to many it is the ultimate prize.
>
> At the heart of its story is Amlaruil, Queen of All Elves. When Evermeet comes under massive, devastating attack, her sacrifice holds the last hope of saving the elven homeland.

Comment: That's not it, but I appreciate your continued help! These Forgotten Realm books seemed promising, but they seem much more detailed and epic than the book I remember. It could very well have been part of a series, though. If I ever figure it out, I'll share it. Although, based on your knowledge I have more faith in you finding it before I do. The only things I remember with any certainty are: the main character was a young woman with long silver hair from the moon realm, promised to the sun prince, both traveled to earth and it was not sci-fi (no spaceships).

Comment: @Aslinn164 - I'd suggesting re-writing this question from scratch. Get rid of all of that Bard crap and just tell us all the things that you remember about the actual novel